# Facebook fan-gate doesn't work consistently

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using this code to check if the user has "liked" the page before going into my app.

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
        // Create our Application instance.
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId' => 'APPID',
          'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
          'cookie' => true,
        ));
        $session = $this->facebook->getSession();
        if(!empty($session)) {
            $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
            $fql_multiquery_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token='.$access_token;
            $fql_multiquery_result = file_get_contents($fql_multiquery_url);
            $fql_multiquery_obj = json_decode($fql_multiquery_result, true);
            $liked = false;
            foreach($fql_multiquery_obj['data'] as $like){
                if($like['id'] == 'PageID'){
                    $liked = true;
                }
            }
            if($liked){
                $data['main_content'] = 'welcome_message';
            } else {
                $data['main_content'] = 'before_like';
            }
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        } else {
            $req_perms = "publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,email,read_stream,user_likes";
            $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=> 1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms' => $req_perms, 'redirect_uri' => 'APP REDIRECT URL'));
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";exit;
        }
```

(I know looping through your likes isn't the best solution, but it seems to work the most consistent for me).

It works for me just fine (and a couple other users in the office works fine too), but it fails for a few users (of course they send me no error message). Is there a better way I can check for likes and have it be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get to a specific page like this:

```
$resp = $this->api('/me/likes/'.$page_id);
$is_fan = (count($resp['data']) !== 0);
```

However this doesn't help if facebook's internal cache is acting up, also if this request runs on a facebook tab, the signed request should also have the fan/no_fan information in [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (see the part about fields and values). In my experience the `signed_request` seemed to be the most reliable.

#### P.S.:

You seem to be using a fairly old version of the php sdk, the `getSession()` method [have been deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/).

Comment: So has 'req_perms', you should probably look at the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation again

Answer (score 0):

```
function parsePageSignedRequest() {
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
  $encoded_sig = null;
  $payload = null;
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
  $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
  return $data;
}
return false;
```

}

```
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];

//check for page liked or not
if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest())
{
  if($signed_request->page->liked) {
      echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />";
  } else {
      echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='notfanstyle.css' />";
  }
}
```

:) try this, it worked for me.